# Line and car detection: Merge two videos in opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I'm looking for the ways of how merge 2 videos. I have 2 files (car_det.py, line_det.py) that separately works perfectly. However, I need them in one video. It perfectly works for "vehicle" to record output video, but produces troubles with "line" variable.

```
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture('video6.mp4')
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 30.0, (640,480))
while (video_capture.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()
    if ret:
        vehicle  = processVideo(video_capture)
        line = processImage(frame)
        out.write(vehicle)
        cv2.imshow("vehicle", vehicle)
        cv2.imshow("line", line)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break
video_capture.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: What does "troubles with "line" variable" mean? What _kind_ of "trouble" is this code causing or running into?

Comment: Not a CV2 user, but in the code you only write the vehicle and not line. You do show both vehicle and line, however. If this doesn't fix it, could you please try and enhance the question - [stating the problem clearly is half of fix](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

If "merge" means merging two videos frame by frame, you must open two videos first like this.

```
video_capture1 = cv2.VideoCapture('video1.mp4')
video_capture2 = cv2.VideoCapture('video2.mp4')
```

And in loop, need to get frames of each video.

```
ret, frame1 = video_capture1.read()
ret, frame2 = video_capture2.read()
```

Next, let's merge. If there are no overlapped part between two videos, then simple add would work.

```
resultFrame = frame1 + frame2;
```

Then, write this frame on VideoWriter.

```
out.write(resultFrame)
```